# Redirection issue to Dropbox app from my app in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, redirect, dropbox

My app has `DropboxSDK` incorporated. There are some pdf in the Dropbox and those pdf has annotations. The annotations include numbers that has to be searched. The business logic is - if the number can not be found, a warning message in a alertView will appear and it works well if my device doesn't have Dropbox installed.

Now, if the Dropbox is installed, and the number from the pdf can not be found, my app redirects me to the Dropbox app.

I don't know what is going on and why it is redirecting to the Dropbox app.

Can anyone please help me.

P.S. My app is not a web based app, so the redirection is not happening from Safari or web view.

Comment: Are you referring to [this Dropbox for iOS SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/sdks/ios)? It sounds like you may be calling the `linkFromController` method when you didn't mean to.

Comment: Thank you. I found out later, that was the reason. Can you put your suggestion as an answer because that was exactly causing the issue.